# FILE_FLAG_POSIX_SEMANTICS does not work

Tags: c++, winapi, posix

I wrote a simple test, but it's not working. Why `CreateFile` with `FILE_FLAG_POSIX_SEMANTICS` flag allows me to open the file named "stamp.oS" on an NTFS disk in the second case?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  auto h = CreateFileA("c:\\stamp.oS", GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 
    FILE_FLAG_POSIX_SEMANTICS, NULL);

  if (h == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    std::cout << "bad first try" << std::endl;
  else
  {
    std::cout << "yeah first" << std::endl;
    CloseHandle(h);
  }


  h = CreateFileA("c:\\stamp.os", GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING,
    FILE_FLAG_POSIX_SEMANTICS, NULL);

  if (h == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    std::cout << "bad second try" << std::endl;
  else
  {
    std::cout << "yeah second" << std::endl;
    CloseHandle(h);
  }

  system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
yeah first
yeah second
```

Comment: because file system, which handle this request, ignore `OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE` flag in object attributes. better question - why you use `CreateFileA` instead `CreateFileW`

Comment: The obcaseinsensitive registry key matters.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/39116635/17034